# Is there a .k5login equivalent on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, su, kerberos

Having obtained a Kerberos ticket, I can switch identities on Linux and BSD machines with `su` (or `ksu`), because the target account lists my main principal in its `~/.k5login`.

Can the same authorization be made in the Windows world somehow?

Comment: Are you looking for the [runas command](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html)?

Comment: Yes, `runas` -- as well as being to login without password, by presenting the Kerberos ticket obtained earlier on the other machine (the one running the Remote Desktop client).

Answer (score 1):

Standard Windows only does user/password and cannot use the Kerberos ticket.
You need to use third-party software for that.

The article
[Pass the key](https://www.thehacker.recipes/ad/movement/kerberos/ptk),
from the website The Hacker Recipes, lists two such free and open-source
products:

[**Rubeus**](https://github.com/GhostPack/Rubeus)

```
# with an NT hash
Rubeus.exe asktgt /domain:$DOMAIN /user:$USER /rc4:$NThash /ptt
# with an AES 128 key
Rubeus.exe asktgt /domain:$DOMAIN /user:$USER /aes128:$NThash /ptt
# with an AES 256 key
Rubeus.exe asktgt /domain:$DOMAIN /user:$USER /aes256:$NThash /ptt
```

[**mimikatz**](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz)

```
# with an NT hash
sekurlsa::pth /user:$USER /domain:$DOMAIN /rc4:$NThash /ptt
# with an AES 128 key
sekurlsa::pth /user:$USER /domain:$DOMAIN /aes128:$aes128_key /ptt
# with an AES 256 key
sekurlsa::pth /user:$USER /domain:$DOMAIN /aes256:$aes256_key /ptt
```

See the documentation of the tools to further understand their
capabilities.

You might prefer the article
[Pass the ticket](https://www.thehacker.recipes/ad/movement/kerberos/ptt),
which adds the following methods:

```
# use a .kirbi file
kerberos::ptt $ticket_kirbi_file

# use a .ccache file
kerberos::ptt $ticket_ccache_file

Rubeus.exe ptt /ticket:$ticket_kirbi_file
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, but "Standard Windows" is what I must use :(

Comment: In that case, I don't know of a solution.